# slide down after 500ms mouse stand on element jquery

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I want slide Down(or Up) occur when mouse enter emelent and stop on it for 500ms, this mean I don't want slide down or up triggered only with mouse passed on my element fast, **I want slide Down triggered only when mouse stop on element for 500ms**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for user26409021

This work for me

```
var myTimeout;
    $('.front-box').each(function(){
    var element=this;
    $(this).hover(function(){
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $(element).find('.hover-img').slideDown('4000');
    }, 500);
},function(){
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
    $(element).find('.hover-img').slideUp('4000');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var myTimeout;
$('div').mouseenter(function() {
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('div').slideToggle('slow');
    }, 1000);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9w6e5qfc/).